# spark-shell throws java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException on running

Tags: apache-spark, bigdata

When I execute `run-example SparkPi`, for example, it works perfectly, but
when I run `spark-shell`, it throws these exceptions:

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.apache.spark.unsafe.Platform (file:/C:/big_data/spark-3.2.0-bin-hadoop3.2-scala2.13/jars/spark-unsafe_2.13-3.2.0.jar) to constructor java.nio.DirectByteBuffer(long,int)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.apache.spark.unsafe.Platform
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 3.2.0
      /_/

Using Scala version 2.13.5 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 11.0.9.1)
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.
21/12/11 19:28:36 ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor.addReplClassLoaderIfNeeded(Executor.scala:909)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor.<init>(Executor.scala:160)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.local.LocalEndpoint.<init>(LocalSchedulerBackend.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.local.LocalSchedulerBackend.start(LocalSchedulerBackend.scala:132)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl.start(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:220)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:581)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2690)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.$anonfun$getOrCreate$2(SparkSession.scala:949)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:201)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:943)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.createSparkSession(Main.scala:114)
        at $line3.$read$$iw.<init>(<console>:5)
        at $line3.$read.<init>(<console>:4)
        at $line3.$read$.<clinit>(<console>)
        at $line3.$eval$.$print$lzycompute(<synthetic>:6)
        at $line3.$eval$.$print(<synthetic>:5)
        at $line3.$eval.$print(<synthetic>)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(IMain.scala:670)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request.loadAndRun(IMain.scala:1006)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.$anonfun$doInterpret$1(IMain.scala:506)
        at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader.asContext(ScalaClassLoader.scala:36)
        at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader.asContext$(ScalaClassLoader.scala:116)
        at scala.reflect.internal.util.AbstractFileClassLoader.asContext(AbstractFileClassLoader.scala:43)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.loadAndRunReq$1(IMain.scala:505)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.$anonfun$doInterpret$3(IMain.scala:519)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.doInterpret(IMain.scala:519)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:503)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:501)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.$anonfun$quietRun$1(IMain.scala:216)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.shell.ReplReporterImpl.withoutPrintingResults(Reporter.scala:64)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.quietRun(IMain.scala:216)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.shell.ILoop.$anonfun$interpretPreamble$1(ILoop.scala:924)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:333)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.shell.ILoop.interpretPreamble(ILoop.scala:924)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.shell.ILoop.$anonfun$run$3(ILoop.scala:963)
        at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.scala:18)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.shell.ILoop.echoOff(ILoop.scala:90)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.shell.ILoop.$anonfun$run$2(ILoop.scala:963)
        at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.scala:18)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.withSuppressedSettings(IMain.scala:1406)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.shell.ILoop.$anonfun$run$1(ILoop.scala:954)
        at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.scala:18)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.shell.ReplReporterImpl.withoutPrintingResults(Reporter.scala:64)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.shell.ILoop.run(ILoop.scala:954)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.doMain(Main.scala:84)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:59)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:955)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:203)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:1043)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:1052)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 42: spark://DESKTOP-JO73CF4.mshome.net:2103/C:\classes
        at java.base/java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2913)
        at java.base/java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(URI.java:3084)
        at java.base/java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(URI.java:3166)
        at java.base/java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3114)
        at java.base/java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:600)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.ExecutorClassLoader.<init>(ExecutorClassLoader.scala:57)
        ... 67 more
21/12/11 19:28:36 ERROR Utils: Uncaught exception in thread main
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.local.LocalSchedulerBackend.org$apache$spark$scheduler$local$LocalSchedulerBackend$$stop(LocalSchedulerBackend.scala:173)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.local.LocalSchedulerBackend.stop(LocalSchedulerBackend.scala:144)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl.stop(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:927)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.stop(DAGScheduler.scala:2516)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.$anonfun$stop$12(SparkContext.scala:2086)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryLogNonFatalError(Utils.scala:1442)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.stop(SparkContext.scala:2086)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:677)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2690)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.$anonfun$getOrCreate$2(SparkSession.scala:949)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:201)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:943)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.createSparkSession(Main.scala:114)
        at $line3.$read$$iw.<init>(<console>:5)
        at $line3.$read.<init>(<console>:4)
        at $line3.$read$.<clinit>(<console>)
        at $line3.$eval$.$print$lzycompute(<synthetic>:6)
        at $line3.$eval$.$print(<synthetic>:5)
        at $line3.$eval.$print(<synthetic>)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(IMain.scala:670)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request.loadAndRun(IMain.scala:1006)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.$anonfun$doInterpret$1(IMain.scala:506)
        at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader.asContext(ScalaClassLoader.scala:36)
        at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader.asContext$(ScalaClassLoader.scala:116)
        at scala.reflect.internal.util.AbstractFileClassLoader.asContext(AbstractFileClassLoader.scala:43)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.loadAndRunReq$1(IMain.scala:505)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.$anonfun$doInterpret$3(IMain.scala:519)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.doInterpret(IMain.scala:519)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:503)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:501)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.$anonfun$quietRun$1(IMain.scala:216)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.shell.ReplReporterImpl.withoutPrintingResults(Reporter.scala:64)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.quietRun(IMain.scala:216)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.shell.ILoop.$anonfun$interpretPreamble$1(ILoop.scala:924)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:333)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.shell.ILoop.interpretPreamble(ILoop.scala:924)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.shell.ILoop.$anonfun$run$3(ILoop.scala:963)
        at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.scala:18)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.shell.ILoop.echoOff(ILoop.scala:90)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.shell.ILoop.$anonfun$run$2(ILoop.scala:963)
        at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.scala:18)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.withSuppressedSettings(IMain.scala:1406)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.shell.ILoop.$anonfun$run$1(ILoop.scala:954)
        at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.scala:18)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.shell.ReplReporterImpl.withoutPrintingResults(Reporter.scala:64)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.shell.ILoop.run(ILoop.scala:954)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.doMain(Main.scala:84)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:59)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:955)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:203)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:1043)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:1052)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
21/12/11 19:28:36 WARN MetricsSystem: Stopping a MetricsSystem that is not running
21/12/11 19:28:36 ERROR Main: Failed to initialize Spark session.
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor.addReplClassLoaderIfNeeded(Executor.scala:909)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor.<init>(Executor.scala:160)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.local.LocalEndpoint.<init>(LocalSchedulerBackend.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.local.LocalSchedulerBackend.start(LocalSchedulerBackend.scala:132)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl.start(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:220)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:581)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2690)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.$anonfun$getOrCreate$2(SparkSession.scala:949)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:201)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:943)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.createSparkSession(Main.scala:114)
        at $line3.$read$$iw.<init>(<console>:5)
        at $line3.$read.<init>(<console>:4)
        at $line3.$read$.<clinit>(<console>)
        at $line3.$eval$.$print$lzycompute(<synthetic>:6)
        at $line3.$eval$.$print(<synthetic>:5)
        at $line3.$eval.$print(<synthetic>)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(IMain.scala:670)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request.loadAndRun(IMain.scala:1006)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.$anonfun$doInterpret$1(IMain.scala:506)
        at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader.asContext(ScalaClassLoader.scala:36)
        at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader.asContext$(ScalaClassLoader.scala:116)
        at scala.reflect.internal.util.AbstractFileClassLoader.asContext(AbstractFileClassLoader.scala:43)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.loadAndRunReq$1(IMain.scala:505)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.$anonfun$doInterpret$3(IMain.scala:519)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.doInterpret(IMain.scala:519)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:503)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:501)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.$anonfun$quietRun$1(IMain.scala:216)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.shell.ReplReporterImpl.withoutPrintingResults(Reporter.scala:64)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.quietRun(IMain.scala:216)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.shell.ILoop.$anonfun$interpretPreamble$1(ILoop.scala:924)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:333)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.shell.ILoop.interpretPreamble(ILoop.scala:924)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.shell.ILoop.$anonfun$run$3(ILoop.scala:963)
        at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.scala:18)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.shell.ILoop.echoOff(ILoop.scala:90)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.shell.ILoop.$anonfun$run$2(ILoop.scala:963)
        at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.scala:18)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.withSuppressedSettings(IMain.scala:1406)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.shell.ILoop.$anonfun$run$1(ILoop.scala:954)
        at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.scala:18)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.shell.ReplReporterImpl.withoutPrintingResults(Reporter.scala:64)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.shell.ILoop.run(ILoop.scala:954)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.doMain(Main.scala:84)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:59)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:955)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:203)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:1043)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:1052)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 42: spark://DESKTOP-JO73CF4.mshome.net:2103/C:\classes
        at java.base/java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2913)
        at java.base/java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(URI.java:3084)
        at java.base/java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(URI.java:3166)
        at java.base/java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3114)
        at java.base/java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:600)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.ExecutorClassLoader.<init>(ExecutorClassLoader.scala:57)
        ... 67 more
21/12/11 19:28:36 ERROR Utils: Uncaught exception in thread shutdown-hook-0
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor.stop(Executor.scala:333)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor.$anonfun$stopHookReference$1(Executor.scala:76)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHook.run(ShutdownHookManager.scala:214)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager.$anonfun$runAll$2(ShutdownHookManager.scala:188)
        at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.scala:18)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:2019)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager.$anonfun$runAll$1(ShutdownHookManager.scala:188)
        at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.scala:18)
        at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:210)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager.runAll(ShutdownHookManager.scala:188)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anon$2.run(ShutdownHookManager.scala:178)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.spark.shuffle.ShuffleBlockPusher$.<clinit>(ShuffleBlockPusher.scala:465)
        ... 16 more
21/12/11 19:28:36 WARN ShutdownHookManager: ShutdownHook '' failed, java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:205)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ShutdownHookManager.executeShutdown(ShutdownHookManager.java:124)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ShutdownHookManager$1.run(ShutdownHookManager.java:95)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor.stop(Executor.scala:333)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor.$anonfun$stopHookReference$1(Executor.scala:76)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHook.run(ShutdownHookManager.scala:214)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager.$anonfun$runAll$2(ShutdownHookManager.scala:188)
        at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.scala:18)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:2019)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager.$anonfun$runAll$1(ShutdownHookManager.scala:188)
        at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.scala:18)
        at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:210)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager.runAll(ShutdownHookManager.scala:188)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anon$2.run(ShutdownHookManager.scala:178)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.spark.shuffle.ShuffleBlockPusher$.<clinit>(ShuffleBlockPusher.scala:465)
        ... 16 more
```

As I can see it caused by `Illegal character in path at index 42: spark://DESKTOP-JO73CF4.mshome.net:2103/C:\classes`, but I don't understand what does it mean exactly and how to deal with that

How can I solve this problem?

I use Spark 3.2.0 Pre-built for Apache Hadoop 3.3 and later (Scala 2.13)

JAVA_HOME, HADOOP_HOME, SPARK_HOME path variables are set.

Comment: I switched to Spark 2.4.7 and it started working

Comment: I confirm to you that Spark 3.1.2 worked well, 3.2.0 still has some problems

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i face the same problem, i think Spark 3.2 is the problem itself

switched to Spark 3.1.2, it works fine

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same issue. as of April 2022, I've used spark-3.1.3-bin-hadoop3.2 with winutils.exe (hadoop-3.2.0). It worked

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).